# File generator task: "sourceGenerators in Compile" added task runs twice

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

I made a sbt plugin for play frameworks, which has got a sbt task who generates a scala object. Sbt task should run everytime when sources get compiled. Actually when sourceGenerators runs, task get called twice in one compile process.

Code to add task to sourceGenerators:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (myFileGeneratorTask in Compile)
```

I'm using Twirl to generate templates in Playframework. I'm thinking sourceGenerators runs twice because Twirl rerun sourceGenerators process. Am I right or is there another reason why sourceGenerators run my sbt task twice?

How do I have to involve a sbt task which generates a source into sourceManaged, into compile process? So that every time when sourceGenerators in Compile starts, my scala object is known by sourceGenerators without running twice?